# Getting 4K@60Hz via ATI R9 290 display-port on Panasonic TC65-AX-800U

Tags: linux, graphics-card, hdmi, xorg, amd-catalyst

Hi I have an AMD R9 290 card, under linux, with the proprietary Catalyst 14.50.2 driver; the AMD Card only Has HDMI-1.x which can't do 4K@60Hz, but it does have display port which is capable of 4K@60Hz according to the standard.  I need to know how to program the catalyst driver to do 4K at 60Hz.

So far -- I bought a Panasonic TC-65AX800U 4K screen which advertises 4K@60Hz when in "Game mode" over the Display Port, or HDMI-2 cable (Which AMD R290 doesn't have); and so I attached it using display port;

It does do 4K, but so far not at 60Hz, but only between 24 and 31Hz ; and even then the screen sometimes goes blank and says no signal, even when the graphics card says it is outputting signal.

The max resolution I can get at 60Hz is 2560x1440 (3K display) and I'm not the only one having this problem:

http://forums.amd.com/game/messageview.cfm?catid=440&threadid=184071
http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/id-2543369/displayport-60hz-output-issue-r295-panasonic-ax800.html
and many others... but no solutions...

So; I'm wondering if the EDID data is buggy or if there is something I need to do to Xorg.conf to program a proper mode-line to get DP to do 4K @ 60Hz?
Or is it the AMD card itself which is causing the problem, or the driver?

The information in Xorg.log, from the Panasonic EDID probing, shows a maximum dot clock of 305MHz, and 68Khz Horizontal refresh rate; But when I check the manuals, it says  Horizontal refresh rate can go up to 110KHz...
So -- something is not quite right with the EDID...

When I check /var/log/Xorg.log, it lists video modes in the following format:

```
"mode"xHz clockMHz xReso xSync xSyncEnd xTotal  yReso ySync ySyncEnd yTotal
```

A typical example is:

```
Modeline "3840x2160"x31.5  297.00  3840 3850 3880 3890  2160 2168 2178 2425 +hsync -vsync (76.3 kHz)
```

Which has a 297MHz data transfer rate (dot clock). So checking the math:
297000000 / 3890 = 76349Hz (76.3kHz) horizontal refresh rate
and 297000000 / 3890. / 2425. ~= 31.48Hz vertical refresh rate as predicted.

But I suspect that also means that the best which could possibly be done using fastest EDID dotclock reported, eg: of 305MHz is:

305000000. / 3890 / 2425 = 32Hz, which is pathetic.... and nowhere close to 60Hz.

I tried checking the Panasonic settings to see what might affect it;
According to Panasonic, Game mode is supposed to be "on", although it doesn't seem to affect the EDID vales at all.  But I turned it on.  The setting called "Pure 4K" is not mentioned as a requirement to get 4K@60Hz, but I found out that it must be set to "OFF" or else the screen rolls and does not VSYNC correctly when I start X11 in 3840x2160 mode.  But, on the other hand -- EDID values aren't affected by it, so I don't see that it matters unless it's a data packing strategy for compression... all that the menu says is something about needing a true "4:4:4" format in order to be turned on; but not what kind of 4:4:4 format, or any info on the dotclock.

Is it possible to select a lower quality video encoding mode in xorg.conf, than 8 bit per channel RGB, eg: is YCrCb 4:2:0, or 4:4:4 lower quality? and by doing that, could I get more YCrCb pixels per dot clock than RGB pixels?  ( eg: What is the Pure 4K 4:4:4 that Panasonic is requesting ? )

If the Panasonic can't do 4K@60Hz, they are basically doing false advertising ... and I want to make sure I've eliminated any fault on my side before complaining but I'm not sure how to figure out what it's capable of.

If lower quality is possible, how do I inform the Catalyst 14.50.2 (AKA fglrx) Driver to do this using the /etc/X11/xorg.conf file ?

Has anyone ever gotten a Panasonic TC65-AX800U to display 4K content at 60Hz, ever with either HDMI-2 or Display-port, on nvidia or ATI/AMD graphics cards, and did you have to change Xorg.conf to make it work, and what mode & cable did you have to use ?

If there is no solution using Catalyst, then does anyone know if the linux ATI/AMD open source driver is able to configure for 4K@60, given the Panasonic EDID info found in the following Xorg.log ?

```
[  6074.946] (II) fglrx(0): EDID Management option: EDID Management is enabled
[  6074.946] (II) Loading sub module "ddc"
[  6074.946] (II) LoadModule: "ddc"
[  6074.946] (II) Module "ddc" already built-in
[  6075.056] (II) fglrx(0): Output DFP1 using monitor section Monitor4K
[  6075.056] (II) fglrx(0): Output DFP2 has no monitor section
[  6075.056] (II) fglrx(0): Output DFP3 has no monitor section
[  6075.056] (II) fglrx(0): Output DFP4 has no monitor section
[  6075.056] (II) fglrx(0): Output DFP5 has no monitor section
[  6075.056] (II) fglrx(0): Output DFP6 has no monitor section
[  6075.056] (II) fglrx(0): Output DFP7 has no monitor section
[  6075.056] (II) Loading sub module "ddc"
[  6075.056] (II) LoadModule: "ddc"
[  6075.056] (II) Module "ddc" already built-in
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0): Connected Display0: DFP1
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0): Display0 EDID data ---------------------------
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0): Manufacturer: MEI  Model: a296  Serial#: 17
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0): Year: 2014  Week: 0
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0): EDID Version: 1.4
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0): Digital Display Input
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0): 8 bits per channel
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0): Digital interface is DisplayPort
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0): Max Image Size [cm]: horiz.: 144  vert.: 81
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0): Gamma: 2.20
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0): No DPMS capabilities specified
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0): Supported color encodings: RGB 4:4:4 YCrCb 4:4:4 
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0): Default color space is primary color space
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0): First detailed timing is preferred mode
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0): Preferred mode is native pixel format and refresh rate
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0): redX: 0.640 redY: 0.330   greenX: 0.300 greenY: 0.600
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0): blueX: 0.150 blueY: 0.060   whiteX: 0.313 whiteY: 0.329
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0): Supported established timings:
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0): 640x480@60Hz
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0): 800x600@60Hz
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0): 1024x768@60Hz
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0): Manufacturer's mask: 0
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0): Supported standard timings:
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0): #0: hsize: 640  vsize 480  refresh: 60  vid: 16433
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0): #1: hsize: 800  vsize 600  refresh: 60  vid: 16453
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0): #2: hsize: 1024  vsize 768  refresh: 60  vid: 16481
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0): #3: hsize: 1280  vsize 1024  refresh: 60  vid: 32897
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0): Supported detailed timing:
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0): clock: 148.5 MHz   Image Size:  698 x 392 mm
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0): h_active: 1920  h_sync: 2008  h_sync_end 2052 h_blank_end 2200 h_border: 0
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0): v_active: 1080  v_sync: 1084  v_sync_end 1089 v_blanking: 1125 v_border: 0
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0): Established timings III: (not decoded)
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0): Monitor name: Panasonic
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0): Ranges: V min: 23 V max: 61 Hz, H min: 15 H max: 68 kHz, PixClock max 305 MHz
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0): Supported detailed timing:
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0): clock: 297.0 MHz   Image Size:  698 x 392 mm
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0): h_active: 3840  h_sync: 4016  h_sync_end 4104 h_blank_end 4400 h_border: 0
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0): v_active: 2160  v_sync: 2168  v_sync_end 2178 v_blanking: 2250 v_border: 0
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0): Supported detailed timing:
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0): clock: 241.5 MHz   Image Size:  698 x 392 mm
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0): h_active: 2560  h_sync: 2608  h_sync_end 2640 h_blank_end 2720 h_border: 0
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0): v_active: 1440  v_sync: 1443  v_sync_end 1448 v_blanking: 1481 v_border: 0
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0): Supported detailed timing:
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0): clock: 85.5 MHz   Image Size:  698 x 392 mm
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0): h_active: 1366  h_sync: 1436  h_sync_end 1579 h_blank_end 1792 h_border: 0
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0): v_active: 768  v_sync: 771  v_sync_end 774 v_blanking: 798 v_border: 0
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0): Number of EDID sections to follow: 1
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0): EDID (in hex):
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0):     00ffffffffffff0034a996a211000000
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0):     00180104a59051780eee95a3544c9926
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0):     0f505421080031404540614081800101
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0):     010101010101023a801871382d40582c
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0):     4500ba882100001e000000f7000a00c0
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0):     80000000000000000000000000fc0050
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0):     616e61736f6e69630a202020000000fd
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0):     00173d0f441e000a20202020202001b2
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0): End of Display0 EDID data --------------------
[  6075.057] (II) fglrx(0): Dynamic Surface Resizing Enabled
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): EDID for output DFP1
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): Manufacturer: MEI  Model: a296  Serial#: 17
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): Year: 2014  Week: 0
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): EDID Version: 1.4
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): Digital Display Input
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): 8 bits per channel
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): Digital interface is DisplayPort
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): Max Image Size [cm]: horiz.: 144  vert.: 81
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): Gamma: 2.20
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): No DPMS capabilities specified
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): Supported color encodings: RGB 4:4:4 YCrCb 4:4:4 
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): Default color space is primary color space
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): First detailed timing is preferred mode
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): Preferred mode is native pixel format and refresh rate
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): redX: 0.640 redY: 0.330   greenX: 0.300 greenY: 0.600
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): blueX: 0.150 blueY: 0.060   whiteX: 0.313 whiteY: 0.329
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): Supported established timings:
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): 640x480@60Hz
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): 800x600@60Hz
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): 1024x768@60Hz
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): Manufacturer's mask: 0
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): Supported standard timings:
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): #0: hsize: 640  vsize 480  refresh: 60  vid: 16433
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): #1: hsize: 800  vsize 600  refresh: 60  vid: 16453
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): #2: hsize: 1024  vsize 768  refresh: 60  vid: 16481
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): #3: hsize: 1280  vsize 1024  refresh: 60  vid: 32897
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): Supported detailed timing:
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): clock: 148.5 MHz   Image Size:  698 x 392 mm
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): h_active: 1920  h_sync: 2008  h_sync_end 2052 h_blank_end 2200 h_border: 0
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): v_active: 1080  v_sync: 1084  v_sync_end 1089 v_blanking: 1125 v_border: 0
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): Established timings III: (not decoded)
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): Monitor name: Panasonic
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): Ranges: V min: 23 V max: 61 Hz, H min: 15 H max: 68 kHz, PixClock max 305 MHz
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): Supported detailed timing:
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): clock: 297.0 MHz   Image Size:  698 x 392 mm
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): h_active: 3840  h_sync: 4016  h_sync_end 4104 h_blank_end 4400 h_border: 0
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): v_active: 2160  v_sync: 2168  v_sync_end 2178 v_blanking: 2250 v_border: 0
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): Supported detailed timing:
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): clock: 241.5 MHz   Image Size:  698 x 392 mm
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): h_active: 2560  h_sync: 2608  h_sync_end 2640 h_blank_end 2720 h_border: 0
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): v_active: 1440  v_sync: 1443  v_sync_end 1448 v_blanking: 1481 v_border: 0
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): Supported detailed timing:
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): clock: 85.5 MHz   Image Size:  698 x 392 mm
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): h_active: 1366  h_sync: 1436  h_sync_end 1579 h_blank_end 1792 h_border: 0
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): v_active: 768  v_sync: 771  v_sync_end 774 v_blanking: 798 v_border: 0
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): EDID vendor "MEI", prod id 41622
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): Using hsync ranges from config file
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): Using vrefresh ranges from config file
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  148.50  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz eP)
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x768"x0.0   68.25  1280 1328 1360 1440  768 771 778 790 +hsync -vsync (47.4 kHz e)
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x768"x0.0   79.50  1280 1344 1472 1664  768 771 778 798 -hsync +vsync (47.8 kHz e)
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1360x768"x0.0   85.50  1360 1424 1536 1792  768 771 777 795 +hsync +vsync (47.7 kHz e)
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "3840x2160"x0.0  297.00  3840 4016 4104 4400  2160 2168 2178 2250 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "2560x1440"x0.0  241.50  2560 2608 2640 2720  1440 1443 1448 1481 +hsync -vsync (88.8 kHz e)
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   85.50  1366 1436 1579 1792  768 771 774 798 +hsync +vsync (47.7 kHz e)
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "720x576"x0.0   27.00  720 732 796 864  576 581 586 625 -hsync -vsync (31.2 kHz e)
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0   74.25  1920 2448 2492 2640  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (28.1 kHz e)
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "2880x480"x0.0  108.00  2880 2944 3192 3432  480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[  6075.059] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1920x1080i"x0.0   74.25  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1094 1125 interlace +hsync +vsync (33.8 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Not using mode "3840x2160" (vrefresh out of range)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Printing probed modes for output DFP1
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "3840x2160_30"x30.0  297.00  3840 4016 4104 4400  2160 2168 2178 2250 -hsync -vsync (67.5 kHz UP)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x60.0  148.50  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz eP)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "4096x2160_24"x24.0  297.00  4096 5116 5204 5500  2160 2168 2178 2250 +hsync +vsync (54.0 kHz)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "4096x2160"x24.0  297.00  4096 5116 5204 5500  2160 2168 2178 2250 +hsync +vsync (54.0 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "3840x2160"x25.0  305.00  3840 5106 5214 5400  2160 2178 2188 2250 -hsync +vsync (56.5 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "3840x2160_31"x31.5  297.00  3840 3850 3880 3890  2160 2168 2178 2425 +hsync -vsync (76.3 kHz)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "3840x2160_27"x27.8  297.00  3840 3850 3900 4400  2160 2168 2178 2425 +hsync -vsync (67.5 kHz)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "3840x2160_24"x24.0  297.00  3840 5116 5204 5500  2160 2168 2178 2250 -hsync -vsync (54.0 kHz)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "3840x2160"x31.0  297.00  3840 3850 3880 3890  2160 2168 2178 2425 +hsync -vsync (76.3 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "3840x2160"x30.0  297.00  3840 4016 4104 4400  2160 2168 2178 2250 -hsync -vsync (67.5 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "3840x2160"x27.0  297.00  3840 3850 3900 4400  2160 2168 2178 2425 +hsync -vsync (67.5 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "3840x2160"x24.0  297.00  3840 5116 5204 5500  2160 2168 2178 2250 -hsync -vsync (54.0 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "3840x2160"x30.0  296.70  3840 4016 4104 4400  2160 2168 2178 2250 +hsync +vsync (67.4 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "3840x2160"x24.0  296.70  3840 5116 5204 5500  2160 2168 2178 2250 +hsync +vsync (53.9 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "3840x2160"x26.0  295.00  3840 4026 4212 4398  2160 2271 2382 2495 +hsync -vsync (67.1 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "3840x2160"x29.0  290.00  3840 4016 4104 4400  2160 2168 2178 2250 +hsync +vsync (65.9 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "3840x2159"x30.0  295.00  3840 3884 3957 4000  2159 2168 2178 2425 +hsync -vsync (73.8 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "2560x1440"x60.0  241.50  2560 2608 2640 2720  1440 1443 1448 1481 +hsync -vsync (88.8 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "2048x1536"x30.0  296.70  2048 4016 4104 4400  1536 2168 2178 2250 +hsync +vsync (67.4 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "2048x1536"x24.0  296.70  2048 5116 5204 5500  1536 2168 2178 2250 +hsync +vsync (53.9 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1800x1440"x60.0  241.50  1800 2608 2640 2720  1440 1443 1448 1481 +hsync -vsync (88.8 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1856x1392"x60.0  241.50  1856 2608 2640 2720  1392 1443 1448 1481 +hsync -vsync (88.8 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1792x1344"x60.0  241.50  1792 2608 2640 2720  1344 1443 1448 1481 +hsync -vsync (88.8 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1920x1200"x60.0  241.50  1920 2608 2640 2720  1200 1443 1448 1481 +hsync -vsync (88.8 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x59.9  148.35  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.4 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x30.0   74.25  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (33.8 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x24.0   74.25  1920 2558 2602 2750  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (27.0 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x30.0   74.18  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (33.7 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x24.0   74.18  1920 2558 2602 2750  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (27.0 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1600x1200"x60.0  241.50  1600 2608 2640 2720  1200 1443 1448 1481 +hsync -vsync (88.8 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1776x1000"x59.9  148.35  1776 1864 1908 2200  1000 1004 1009 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.4 kHz ez)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1776x1000"x24.0   74.25  1776 2414 2458 2750  1000 1004 1009 1125 +hsync +vsync (27.0 kHz ez)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1776x1000"x30.0   74.18  1776 1864 1908 2200  1000 1004 1009 1125 +hsync +vsync (33.7 kHz ez)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x60.0  148.50  1680 2008 2052 2200  1050 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x59.9  148.35  1680 2008 2052 2200  1050 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.4 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x30.0   74.25  1680 2008 2052 2200  1050 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (33.8 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x24.0   74.25  1680 2558 2602 2750  1050 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (27.0 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x30.0   74.18  1680 2008 2052 2200  1050 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (33.7 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x24.0   74.18  1680 2558 2602 2750  1050 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (27.0 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1400x1050"x60.0  148.50  1400 2008 2052 2200  1050 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1400x1050"x59.9  148.35  1400 2008 2052 2200  1050 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.4 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1400x1050"x30.0   74.25  1400 2008 2052 2200  1050 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (33.8 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1400x1050"x24.0   74.25  1400 2558 2602 2750  1050 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (27.0 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1400x1050"x30.0   74.18  1400 2008 2052 2200  1050 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (33.7 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1400x1050"x24.0   74.18  1400 2558 2602 2750  1050 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (27.0 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1600x900"x59.9  148.35  1600 1864 1908 2200  900 1004 1009 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.4 kHz ez)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1600x900"x24.0   74.25  1600 2414 2458 2750  900 1004 1009 1125 +hsync +vsync (27.0 kHz ez)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1600x900"x30.0   74.18  1600 1864 1908 2200  900 1004 1009 1125 +hsync +vsync (33.7 kHz ez)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x60.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x30.0   74.18  1280 2008 2052 2200  1024 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (33.7 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x24.0   74.18  1280 2558 2602 2750  1024 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (27.0 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1440x900"x59.9  148.35  1440 1864 1908 2200  900 1004 1009 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.4 kHz ez)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1440x900"x24.0   74.25  1440 2414 2458 2750  900 1004 1009 1125 +hsync +vsync (27.0 kHz ez)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1440x900"x30.0   74.18  1440 1864 1908 2200  900 1004 1009 1125 +hsync +vsync (33.7 kHz ez)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x960"x60.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  960 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x960"x30.0   74.18  1280 2008 2052 2200  960 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (33.7 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x960"x24.0   74.18  1280 2558 2602 2750  960 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (27.0 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1366x768"x60.0   85.50  1366 1436 1579 1792  768 771 774 798 +hsync +vsync (47.7 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1366x768"x30.0   74.18  1366 2008 2052 2200  768 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (33.7 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1366x768"x24.0   74.18  1366 2558 2602 2750  768 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (27.0 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1360x768"x60.0   85.50  1360 1424 1536 1792  768 771 777 795 +hsync +vsync (47.7 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1360x768"x30.0   74.18  1360 2008 2052 2200  768 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (33.7 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1360x768"x24.0   74.18  1360 2558 2602 2750  768 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (27.0 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x768"x60.0   79.50  1280 1344 1472 1664  768 771 778 798 -hsync +vsync (47.8 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x768"x30.0   74.18  1280 2008 2052 2200  768 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (33.7 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x768"x24.0   74.18  1280 2558 2602 2750  768 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (27.0 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x720"x60.0   74.25  1280 1390 1430 1650  720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync (45.0 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x720"x59.9   74.18  1280 1390 1430 1650  720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync (45.0 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x720"x30.0   74.18  1280 2008 2052 2200  720 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (33.7 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1280x720"x24.0   74.18  1280 2558 2602 2750  720 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (27.0 kHz e)
[  6075.060] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1024x768"x30.0   74.18  1024 2008 2052 2200  768 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (33.7 kHz e)
[  6075.061] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1024x768"x24.0   74.18  1024 2558 2602 2750  768 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (27.0 kHz e)
[  6075.061] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1024x768"x60.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[  6075.061] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1152x648"x59.9   74.18  1152 1262 1302 1650  648 653 658 750 +hsync +vsync (45.0 kHz ez)
[  6075.061] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "800x600"x30.0   74.18  800 2008 2052 2200  600 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (33.7 kHz e)
[  6075.061] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "800x600"x24.0   74.18  800 2558 2602 2750  600 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (27.0 kHz e)
[  6075.061] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "800x600"x60.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[  6075.061] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "640x480"x30.0   74.18  640 2008 2052 2200  480 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (33.7 kHz e)
[  6075.061] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "640x480"x24.0   74.18  640 2558 2602 2750  480 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (27.0 kHz e)
[  6075.061] (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "640x480"x59.9   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[  6075.061] (II) fglrx(0): EDID for output DFP2
[  6075.061] (II) fglrx(0): EDID for output DFP3
[  6075.061] (II) fglrx(0): EDID for output DFP4
[  6075.061] (II) fglrx(0): EDID for output DFP5
[  6075.061] (II) fglrx(0): EDID for output DFP6
[  6075.061] (II) fglrx(0): EDID for output DFP7
[  6075.061] (II) fglrx(0): Output DFP1 connected
[  6075.061] (II) fglrx(0): Output DFP2 disconnected
[  6075.061] (II) fglrx(0): Output DFP3 disconnected
[  6075.061] (II) fglrx(0): Output DFP4 disconnected
[  6075.061] (II) fglrx(0): Output DFP5 disconnected
[  6075.061] (II) fglrx(0): Output DFP6 disconnected
[  6075.061] (II) fglrx(0): Output DFP7 disconnected
[  6075.061] (II) fglrx(0): Using user preference for initial modes
[  6075.061] (II) fglrx(0): Output DFP1 using initial mode 3840x2160_30
[  6075.061] (II) fglrx(0): Using default gamma of (1.0, 1.0, 1.0) unless otherwise stated.
[  6075.061] (II) fglrx(0): Display dimensions: (1440, 810) mm
[  6075.061] (II) fglrx(0): DPI set to (67, 67)
[  6075.061] (II) fglrx(0): Eyefinity capable adapter detected.
[  6075.061] (II) fglrx(0): Adapter AMD Radeon R9 200 Series has 6 configurable heads and 1 displays connected.
```